# Get relationship data from withPivot on many-to-many pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, eloquent-relationship

**TL/DR:**
I've got a many-to-many relationship between two models using `withPivot` and and `using`. I want to get the related data from the `withPivot` value from a foreign key.

---

I am working with a multi tenancy project, which has a `master` database and `tenant` databases.

Any model in the `App\Tenant\` is currently using the `$connection` attribute.

I have the following structure of my models and their associated tables:

```
- App/Tenant/Match
- App/Tenant/MatchTeam
- App/Team
- App/Ground
```

The relationship between `team` and `match` is `many-to-many`

(a `team` can play multiple `matches`, and a `match` can have many `teams`)

**Match.php**

```
namespace App\Tenant
class Match extends TenantModel

public function teams() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'tenant.match_team', 'match_id', 'team_uuid')
                ->using(MatchTeam::class)            
                ->withPivot('ground_id');
}
```

**Team.php**

```
namespace App
class Team extends Model

protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';

public $incrementing = false;

public function grounds() {
    return $this->hasMany(Ground::class, 'team_uuid', 'uuid');
}

public function matches() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Match::class, 'tenant.match_team', 'team_uuid', 'match_id')
                ->using(MatchTeam::class)            
                ->withPivot('ground_id')
                ;
}
```

**MatchTeam.php**

```
class MatchTeam extends Pivot 

protected $connection = 'tenant';
protected $table = 'match_team';

public function ground() {
    return $this->hasOne(Ground::class);
}
```

**match_team table:**

```
| id |     team_uuid      | match_id | ground_id | 
|----| ------------------ | -------- | --------- |
| 1  | kajdnfgkasdnfadsgn |    1     |    NULL   |
| 2  | lsdjfgsadlkfjglsdj |    2     |     4     |
| 2  | kshdfkjdshfytufjek |    3     |     1     |
```

---

### **QUESTION:**

How can I access the ground data that relates to the `ground_id` field on the `match_team` pivot table?

I'm primarily after something like the the `match->ground->name` which is a relationship on the foreign key on the `match_team` table.

---

I've tried the following:

**MatchController.php**

```
public function show(Match $match) {
    $match = Match::where('id', $match->id)->with('ground')->first();
}
```

But it gives `Call to undefined relationship [ground]`

---

**DD($match) as requested below**

```
Interaction {#215 ▼
#table: "matches"
#connection: "tenant"
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:19 [▶]
#original: array:19 [▶]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "ground" => null
]
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#fillable: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Comment: I've also tried `$match->pivot->ground_id` but get the same error.

Comment: as you see the ground is null so try refactoring the `ground` relation in `Match` model

Comment: The Match model doesn't have a `ground_id` field though. That is the data on the pivot.

Comment: You can only access the `pivot` relationship when you use the `BelongsToMany` relationship: `foreach ($match->teams as $team) { $team->pivot->ground->name; }`

Answer (score 0):

As Your error said there is No Ground Relation in the Match Model
So in your **Match** Model

```
public function ground() {
    return $this->hasOne(Ground::class,'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

EDITED

Since I don't know the table structure

**MAY BE THIS WILL HELP YOU**

> METHOD ONE:

```
if(! is_null($match->pivot->ground))
{
  $groundName = $match->pivot->ground->name;
}else{
    $groundName = 'Ground Not Set';
}
```

> METHOD TWO:

```
$groundName = $match->ground['name'] ??  'Ground Not Set';
```

Comment: I've just added as above, with the `id` and `ground_id` as the respected keys. When I call `return $match->pivot->ground->name;` in my **MatchController** I get `Trying to get property 'ground' of non-object`

Comment: can you post `dd($match)`

Comment: Posted above in OP.